# Print already opened Internet explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, printing

I am trying to print an Internet Explorer page that is already open but it does not work. Code below:

```
 Sub Already_Opened()

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.application")
    intWinCnt = objShell.Windows.Count

    For intWinNo = 0 To (intWinCnt - 1)
      StrWinTitle = objShell.Windows(intWinNo).Document.Title

      If StrWinTitle = "Google" Then
        Set IE = objShell.Windows(intWinNo).Document
        Exit For

      End If

      Next
        Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
        Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2

        'Search box
        IE.getElementsByClassName("gLFyf gsfi")(0).Value = "Earth"

        'Search result Button
        IE.getElementsByClassName("gNO89b")(0).Click

        'Wait 5 Sec
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

        'Print
        IE.execWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
End Sub
```

When I use Excel VBA to open and navigate to Internet explorer and then print it works. Below code works:

```
Sub New_IE()

    Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
    Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.google.co.uk/"

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set Doc = IE.Document

    'Search box
    Doc.getElementsByClassName("gLFyf gsfi")(0).Value = "Earth"

    'Search result Button
    Doc.getElementsByClassName("gNO89b")(0).Click

    'Print
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    IE.execWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER

End Sub
```

Comment: You should include more information than "it does not work". What happens exactly? If there is an error, what is it? And on what line?

Comment: Please provide your post with error mesages that you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to check both sample codes and I found the cause for the issue.

You said that the print code is working for the 2nd code example but not for the 1st code example.

If you check the line of code that prints the page then you can notice that you are using the **IE browser object**. (in the 2nd example)

If you see the 1st code sample then you can notice that you are assigning the **IE document** to the **IE object**.

```
Set IE = objShell.Windows(intWinNo).Document
```

You need to assign the **IE browser object** instead of **document object** to fix the issue.

Below is the modified code that is working fine.

```
 Sub Already_Opened()
Dim IE As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.application")
    intWinCnt = objShell.Windows.Count

    For intWinNo = 0 To (intWinCnt - 1)
      StrWinTitle = objShell.Windows(intWinNo).document.Title

      If StrWinTitle = "Google" Then
        Set IE = objShell.Windows(intWinNo)
        Exit For

      End If

      Next
        Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
        Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2

        'Search box
        IE.document.getElementsByClassName("gLFyf gsfi")(0).Value = "Earth"

        'Search result Button
        IE.document.getElementsByClassName("gNO89b")(0).Click

        'Wait 5 Sec
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

        'Print
        IE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER
End Sub
```

You can try to run this sample on your side and let us know whether it works for you or not. Let us know if anything is unclear. I will try to provide suggestions for it.

Comment: What is the alternative to `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")` ? I want the Internet explorer page to fully load then carry on to the  next line of Code in example Print page after the page is completely loaded then run `IE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER`